# Xcode iPhone app to Android app using PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I already build an iPhone app in Xcode,i came to know that we can open the Xcode app in PhoneGap.

Is it possible to build Android app with some minimal changes from iPhone app code.

Or any other suggestion related to this.

Answer (score 3):

**PhoneGap** is to create web-based mobile applications. The logic behind is that, you make mobile web page and **PhoneGap** packs it for **Android, iOS** etc.

You can not convert **Native iOS App** to **Native Android App**.